# Realm: change field name for migration

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-migration

I'd like to change field name in Realm DB migration process.
It seems that changing field name is not supported, and only copy-and-remove is the only way to do.

is this correct?
It consumes lots of time.

Below code is my trial to change field `value` to `summary` in copy-and-remove manner.

```
RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();
schema.get("Invoice")
.transform(new RealmObjectSchema.Function() {
    @Override
    public void apply(DynamicRealmObject obj) {
        obj.set("summary", obj.getString("value"));
    }
})
.removeField("value");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably what you need is a method: **renameField**

Example:

```
RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();
schema.get("Invoice").renameField("value", "summary");
```